# How jQuery propagation works?

Tags: jquery, html

I actually work on a web app with social network parts.

The purpose of this code will be to display posts for a particular user (ie this user may have voted 'like' or 'dislike' for one of many of the displayed posts) :

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${requestScope['postVotes']}">
                <div class="thread" data-post="${post.key.messageId}"
                    data-vote="${post.value}"
                    data-response-level-message="${post.key.responseLevelMessage}">
                    <c:if test="${post.key.responseLevelMessage == 0}">
                        <hr>
                        <font size="2"> Le <fmt:formatDate
                                value="${post.key.messageDate}" /> par <a
                            href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CentralStation?section=votePage&CurrentContext=${post.key.messageId}">${post.key.messageSender}</a><br>
                            <br> ${post.key.messageTitle}<br>
                            ${post.key.messageContent}<br>
                            <p class="postId"></p>
                        </font>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${post.key.responseLevelMessage > 0}">
                        <font size="1"> <a
                            href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CentralStation?section=votePage&CurrentContext=${post.key.messageId}">${post.key.messageSender}</a><br>
                            <br> ${post.key.messageContent}<br>
                            <p class="postId"></p>
                        </font>
                    </c:if>

                    <input type="image" class="like" src="img/up.png"
                        data-vote="${post.value}" value="Like"> 
                    <input
                        type="image" class="dislike" src="img/down.png"
                        data-vote="${post.value}" value="Dislike">
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
```

Once the list of posts is displayed, jQuery code will be used to manage voting by the user.
I have to say that I'm a beginner in JS/jQuery, and my question will focus on a particular behaviour of jQuery I don't understand.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.thread').each(function () {
    //Previons function
    var thread = $(this);
    var val = thread.data("vote");
    thread.find("p").text(val);
    if (val == 1) {
      thread.find(".like").addClass('voted');
    }
    else if (val == -1) {
      thread.find(".dislike").addClass('voted');
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.thread').each(function () {
    var thread = $(this);

    //Treat like button
    thread.on('click', this.children("input.like"), function () {
        //Retrive vode and increment
      var vote = thread.data("vote");
      if(vote <= 0){
          vote = 1;
      }
      else if (vote == 1) {
          vote = 0;
      }
      //modify data-vote
      thread.data("vote", vote);
      //print vote
      thread.find("p").text(vote);
      if (vote == 1) {
        thread.find(".like").addClass('voted');
        thread.find(".dislike").removeClass('voted');
      } else if (vote == 0){
        thread.find(".dislike").removeClass('voted');
        thread.find(".like").removeClass('voted');
      }
    });
    //Treat dislike button
    thread.on('click', this.children("input.dislike"), function () {
        //Retrive vode and increment
        var vote = thread.data("vote");
        if(vote >= 0){
          vote = -1;
        }
        else if (vote == -1) {
          vote = 0;
        }
        //modify data-vote
        thread.data("vote", vote);
        //print vote
        thread.find("p").text(vote);
        if (vote == -1) {
          thread.find(".like").removeClass('voted');
          thread.find(".dislike").addClass('voted');
        } else if (vote == 0){
          thread.find(".dislike").removeClass('voted');
          thread.find(".like").removeClass('voted');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

With the code above, the user will be able to click on button "like" or "dislike", or to clear their vote.

If I use this code (management of the "like" button) the execution of the code won't stop and will then execute the "dislike" button code :

```
//Treat like button
    thread.on('click', **this.children("input.like")**, function () {...

//Treat dislike button
        thread.on('click', **this.children("input.dislike")**, function () {...
```

But if I use this one, everything's fine, only the "like" click will be treated :

```
//Treat like button
    thread.on('click', **'input[value="Like"]'**, function () {...

//Treat dislike button
    thread.on('click', **'input[value="Dislike"]'**, function () {...
```

So my question is about propagation (I guess) :

WHY, in the first case, clicking on the "like" button will execute the "like" part of the code then also the "dislike" one ?

WHY, in the second case, clicking on the "like" button is OK, stopping the treatment at the right time ?

Asking such a question is to really understand the behaviour of the jQuery. I've read many articles on the Web and a lot of W3school pages about jQuery, but this is not clear for me.

Thanx by advance.